# How to print a report automatically as soon as it loads with DynamicReports?

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I wrote this app that manages clients, I am generating reports with *DynamicReports*.

I have created an option in my app that generates a report for each client in a press of a button.

For Example: if I have 5 clients, I press "generate reports" and 5 reports are opened, 1 for each client.

Is there a way to automatically send the report to a printer once it's loaded?

Now, I have to press print manually 5 times, once for each report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
report.print();
```

to every report which is being created.

Answer (score 1):

report.print(); will print using the default printer without asking your choices, to show printer dialog you must use :
`report.print(true);`